# Evaluate $\int\sqrt{4x^2+8x}dx$ using $\int\sqrt{u^2-a^2}dx=\frac u2\sqrt{u^2-a^2}-\frac{a^2}{2}\ln|u+\sqrt{u^2-a^2}|+C.$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I completed the square to get $$2 \sqrt{(x+1)^2 - 1}$$

set  $u=x+1$ and $a=1$, and you end up with

$$(x+1) \sqrt{(x+1)^2 - 1} - \ln\left\lvert x+1 + \sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}\right\rvert+C$$

This is not the right answer. I don't see how you could simplify it more, but even if you could it would still be wrong (I put this and the answer given by Symbolab.com into Desmos.com and they didn't line up).

Comment: Well, $(x+1)^2-1=x(x+2)$ but I do not think you can simplify it further

Comment: But isn't $\frac{u}{2} = \frac{x+1}{2}$ and isn't $\frac{a^2}{2}=\frac12$ ? What happened to your factors of $\frac12$ in each of these?

Comment: The 2 on the outside of the square root cancels them out.

Comment: How are you checking if the answer is right or wrong? You don't need to factor out the $4$ when you complete the square as $\sqrt{4x^2+8x}=\sqrt{(2x+2)^2-4}$, although you should still get the correct answer.

Comment: As I said in the question, I used Symbolab.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is equivalent to the answer provided by [Symoblab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%5Csqrt%7B4x%5E%7B2%7D%2B8x%7D)

$$x\sqrt{x^2+2x}-\ln\left\lvert x + \sqrt{x^2+2x}+1\right\rvert+\sqrt{x^2+2x}+C$$

since starting from

$$(x+1) \sqrt{(x+1)^2 - 1} - \ln\left\lvert x+1 + \sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}\right\rvert+C$$

we have that

$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2 - 1}=\sqrt{x^2+2x}$$

therefore

$$(x+1) \sqrt{(x+1)^2 - 1}=x\sqrt{x^2+2x}+\sqrt{x^2+2x}$$
and
$$\ln\left\lvert x+1 + \sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}\right\rvert=\ln\left\lvert x + \sqrt{x^2+2x}+1\right\rvert$$

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the "+ 1" when entering the Symbolab solution into Desmos.